# How to create a Show More button in this .TPL file

Tags: button, module, show

I have downloaded a template with a module called Publications. When the News Page is loaded it calls this .tpl file:

```
{title}{$category.title}{/title}
<div class="newsPage">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>

    {foreach from=$articles item=entry name=articles}
        {if $smarty.foreach.articles.first}<dl><br />{/if}
        <dt><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/publications/{$category.id}/{$entry.id}/{$entry.title|replace:' ':'-'|escape:"urlpathinfo"}.html" class="title"></dt>
        <dd>{$entry.description}</dd>
        {if $smarty.foreach.articles.last}</dl></a>{/if}
    {foreachelse}
        [[There are no articles available at this time]]
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

And there's the problem. If there are 1000 articles, all of them will be loaded and no pages will be created.

I'm trying to create a "show more" button with only the latest 4 articles displayed at first and then when the "show more" button is clicked, the next 4 articles will be displayed, and so on...

Is that possible? Can anyone help me with new ways to create a dynamic news section with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Changed the `<dl> <dt> <dd>` to `<ul> <li>` and then:

```
    var vis = 5;
$('.news li').slice(vis).hide();

var $more = $('<a href="#">Mais</a>')
    $more.click(function(){
        $('.news li:hidden').slice(0,vis).show();
        if($('.news li:hidden').length == 0)
            $more.hide();
    });
$('.newsPage ul').after($more);
```

Answer (score 0):

i still didnt install my editor, but you can give a div or any thing some property, which make that object hidden, i'm not sure if it was block, or hidden it self,

then you can also give it an id, and refer to it with java script, and as you already know a query language like jQuery, you can do it even simpler to refer to the div element, and change its property, (i didnt worked with jQuery), if it's about to be as a toltip, you can use your parent div/ image/ button/ any thing:

```
[style]:hover{display:block;}
```

for styles which normaly are:

```
[style]{display:none;}
```

or instead of display, u can use

```
[style]:hover{visibility:visible;}
```

for stle which are like this:

```
[style]{visibility:hidden;}
```

this is a ways which most of sites menus take advantage of